# Windows 7 Transfer

Tags: windows-7, windows, reinstall

Okay, here's the deal, I upgraded my motherboard, RAM, CPU, but not hard drive. I figured this was my first build on my own it wouldn't be an issue with windows 7. The computer asks me to enter in recovery mode.

Something along the lines of "you're using this windows key for an unknown computer..ERROR!!" Which isn't fair. But I digress..

What I have is a Mac laptop (don't rip me apart), I downloaded a .iso file from the web, I have the key. I want to create a bootable USB so I can just reinstall the same windows with the same key. How should I go about this?

Comment: Is your Windows 7 a retail version, or did it come with the hardware?  If you went to a store(or website) and bought windows 7 then you should just call up microsoft and most of the time you can just the automated system to reset the license key.  Sometimes you have to speak to an actual person tell them you upgraded the hardware and they should reset it.  I have done it before many times on my PC, as a frequent upgrader.

Comment: The way I bought it was actually through my school. I'm a CS major and they sell us copies for 5 dollars. I think they have something worked out with microsoft. So it's a very odd situation

Comment: Your school might have more detail on the reset process. You might have to dig.

Comment: @AngusFisher Just call microsoft you can be done and over in less than 10min.  When you go to the activation window where you get the error there should be a phone number to call.